# How can I transform a custom overlay in Google Maps to account for projection?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, css, google-maps-api-3, proj4js

I'm developing an application that uses Google Maps API v3.  I want to make custom overlays that are squares exactly 1000km on each side (each overlay is actually a 1000x1000 transparent png, with each pixel representing 1 square km).  My current implementation is this:

```
function PngOverlay(map,loc) {
    this._png = null;
    this._location = loc; //lat,lng of the square's center
    this.setMap(map);
}

PngOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

PngOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    this._png = new Element('image',{ //using mootools
    'src': pngForLoc(this._location),
    'styles': {
        'width': 1000,
        'height': 1000,         
        'position': 'absolute'
    }
});

var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(this._png);
}

PngOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this._png.parentNode.removeChild(this._png);
    this._png = null;
}

PngOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
    var dp = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this._location);     
    var ps = this._png.getSize();

    var t = dp.y - (ps.y / 2);
    this._png.setStyle('top',t);

    var l = dp.x - (ps.x / 2);
    this._png.setStyle('left',l);
}
```

My question is this: what, if anything, do I need to do to account for Google Maps' projection?  My limited understanding of Mercator is that it preserves horizontal distance but not vertical.  How can I appropriately transform() my png to account for that?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough information, but you might find the open source proj4js library useful as this can perform various projection transformations, eg. To Google's Spherical Mercator projection system.